# Label on UIButton not laid out correctly with autolayout

Tags: ios8, uibutton, autolayout, uikit, uistoryboard

I have an app which I'm updating to auto layout and size classes and I'm getting some weird behaviour with the label on a button.

The button should be a circle and have a label in the centre. I'm implementing my own subclass so I can reuse it.

Here's the storyboard:

[image: Storyboard]

[image: Storyboard 2]

and the code for the class which extends UIButton:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self) {
        [self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected-green"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted                                                                                                                                                                                               ];

        self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor tlbWhiteColor].CGColor;
        self.layer.borderWidth = 10;

    }
    return self;
}

-(void) layoutSubviews {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2;
}
```

With this the appears as expected but there is no label. On debugging I see that the frame of the label has 0 height and width. So I extended layoutSubviews:

```
-(void) layoutSubviews {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2;
    if (self.titleLabel.frame.size.width == 0) {
        [self.titleLabel sizeToFit];
        [self setNeedsLayout];
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
    }

}
```

The label then appears, but it's in the wrong place:

[image: Screenshot]

The only extra info I can offer is that in Reveal the button has weird height and width constraints added:

[image: Reveal]

The titleInsets are all at 0.

Help hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was a real school boy error.

When the docs said 'The implementation of this method is empty before iOS 6' I for some reason took this to mean there's no need to call super on `layoutSubviews`.

So the fix was:

```
-(void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];  // <<<<< THIS WAS MISSING
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the layoutSubviews override. I think it's a hack and it's hiding your real issue.

What are the constraints on the 'Go' label? How are you centering it in the UIButton? Also what is the height constraint on the label?

My suggestion would be to put both the UIButton and the Go label inside a container view and centre the label inside the container view. The container view should have the same height and width as the UIButton inside it.

Also are you changing the frames of the views programmatically somewhere in the app? Those weird constraints you talk about in reveal point to that.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. The go label isn't a label it's the title of the button ([self.titleLabel sizeToFit]; etc). I'll double check I don't have some other code overriding it.

Comment: also, the reason the corner radius code is in the layout subviews is that before then the button hasn't been laid out and so it doesn't make a circle. if you can suggest the non-hacky place to put it that would be good. I'll doe the other checks

Comment: No extra code affecting the layout. The button extends UIButton. The View controller has no code affecting the layout and nor does it's parent. The only things changed are the background colour of the whole view and adding a button the navigation bar which happens in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirements:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    view_1.layer.cornerRadius = 10; //view_1 is white color
    view_1.layer.masksToBounds = YES;


    view_2.layer.cornerRadius = _view_2.frame.size.width/2;//view_2 is green color
    view_2.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
```

**output**
[image: output]

Comment: Thanks for this @yuyutsu. The main disadvantage of this approach is that the Go! label isn't part of the button which means it won't change state when the button is pressed and so not feel as much like a real button.

That said, if I can't get the normal button working as expected it might be my only option.